# How to assign argv to a pointer variable in C?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, argv

I'm trying to print the arguments passed to the C program, and I want to do it multiple times. Below is the code. You can see, I have created a *count* variable and set to *argc* before each *while* loop. Is there something similar to do with *argv* so that it could reset to `argv[0]` before *while* loop? It's an array pointer and I didn't find a proper way to do it.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int count = argc;
    while (count-- > 0)
    {
        printf("%s%s", *argv++, (count > 0) ? " " : "");
    }
    printf("\n");

    count = argc;
    while (count-- > 0)
    {
        // how to reset argv to point to argv[0] before calling *argv++
        printf((count > 0) ? "%s " : "%s", *argv++);
    }
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Create a variable of the same type as `argv` and assign.

Comment: You could use `argv[count]` and never get to *reset*.

Comment: Keep in mind that arrays decay to pointers when used in function parameters. This means for `argv` you actually need `char const **` to hold a copy.

Comment: You need to check if `int main(int argc, char const *argv[])` is a valid non-standard form of main() for your compiler before anything else. The allowed types of main() is defined by the compiler, never by the programmer.

Comment: @Lundin yes indeed, the standard says that `argv` & `argc` have to be modifiable at any level of indirection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your definition of `argv` is wrong. From the C11 standard  §5.1.2.2.1/2::

> The parameters argc and argv and the strings pointed to by the argv
> array shall be modiﬁable by the program, and retain their last-stored
> values between program startup and program termination.

It should be `char **argv` or `char *argv[]`

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int count = argc;

    char **savedArgv = argv;
    while (count--)
    {
        printf("%s%s", *argv++, (count > 0) ? " " : "");
    }
    printf("\n");

    count = argc;
    argv = savedArgv;
    while (count--)
    {
        // how to reset argv to point to argv[0] before calling *argv++
        printf((count > 0) ? "%s " : "%s", *argv++);
    }
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/Me4Pq8

Comment: ```char **savedArgv = argv;``` works! Thanks!